# Настройка полей в плагине Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Создал план для woocommerce, сам плагин работает корректно, но есть проблема с меню.
При активации плагина отображается пустое содержание корневой вкладки настроек.
Вкладка настроек самого плагина, работает корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Добавляем во вкладку Интеграции настройки плагина
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sections_products', 'ronbel_ms_add_section');
function ronbel_ms_add_section($sections)
{
    $sections["ronbel_ms_plugin"] = __('Ронбел + Мой Склад');
    return ($sections);
}


// Добавляем настройки плагина
add_filter('woocommerce_get_settings_products', 'ronbel_ms_add_settings', 10, 2);
function ronbel_ms_add_settings($settings, $current_section)
{
    $settings = array();

    if ($current_section == "ronbel_ms_plugin") {
        // Заголовок плагина
        $settings[] = array(
          "name" => __('Ронбел + Мой Склад'),
          "type" => "title",
          "desc" => __('Настройки плагина для WooCommerce'),
        );

        $settings[] = array(
          "id"    => "ronbel_ms_user",
          "title" => "Логин Мой Склад",
          "type"  => "text"
        );

        $settings[] = array(
          "id"    => "ronbel_ms_password",
          "title" => "Пароль Мой Склад",
          "type"  => "password"
        );

        // Конец настроек
        $settings[] = array(
          "type"  => "sectionend"
        );
    }


    return ($settings);
}
```

Comment: Нужно убрать $settings = array();

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!